# pass array from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Model:

Grabs data from mySQL with the value: `array['10','5','2']` and puts it in the session data

Controller:

Puts that session data into an array to pass to the view:

```
$fubar = array(
'ex1' => $this->session->userdata('ex1')
    );
$this->load->view('view', $fubar);
```

View:

```
echo $ex1;
```

The view will spit out the array: `array['10','5','2']`
How do I parse that array to get the individual values (10, 5, or 2)?
For example, `echo $ex1['1'];` will spit out the first 1 characters: `ar` but I want it to return the value `5`

I think perhaps I may not be storing the array properly in mySQL, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please, put `var_dump($fubar);` before `$this->load->view('view', $fubar);`
What does it display?

Comment: var_dump:  array(4) { ["ex1"]=> string(21) "array['40','20','10']" ["ex2"]=> string(21) "array['80','40','20']" ["ex3"]=> bool(false) ["date"]=> string(10) "2012-09-08" }

Comment: So, the arrays are not arrays at all, they're just strings.  How do I parse those strings and save them as arrays?

Comment: There is `eval(<php code here>)`. But it's not safe. It's very strange that you save array as string. it's better to use serialize($your_array) and unserialize($your_serialized_array) functions or json_encode() and json_decode() functions.
In conclusion:
1. Save in session: serialize($your_array);
2. Extract from session: unserialize($this->session->userdata('ex1'))

Comment: Why are your arrays being returned as strings? Post your model, or whatever is making this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fubar['ex1'] = $this->session->userdata('ex1');
$this->load->view('view', $fubar);
```

Now Try

```
    $ex1[0];
    $ex1[1];
```

Comment: This is exactly the same thing than `$fubar = array('ex1' => $this->session->userdata('ex1') );`